# Zeep : Unable to set request with payload which has another namespace

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, zeep

[AdaptiveAuthentication.txt](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/files/1344825/AdaptiveAuthentication.txt)
Zeep Version : 2.4.0

Hi,

I am new to Zeep and could able to construct soap client and parse response.
Am facing issue with one of my requests, which we cant construct based on payload.

Request :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.csd.rsa.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body><ws:updateUser>
     <ws:request>
        <ws:credentialManagementRequestList>
           <ws:acspManagementRequestData>
              <ws:credentialProvisioningStatus>ACTIVE</ws:credentialProvisioningStatus>
              <ws:payload xsi:type="ns835:OOBSMSManagementRequest" xmlns:ns835="http://ws.oobsms.csd.rsa.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <ws1:action xmlns:ws1="http://ws.oobgen.csd.rsa.com">ADD</ws1:action>
                 <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                 <ws1:contactList xmlns:ws1="http://ws.oobgen.csd.rsa.com">
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <ws1:isDefault>true</ws1:isDefault>
                    <ws1:phoneNumber>${#Project#phoneNumber}</ws1:phoneNumber>
                    <ws1:countryCode>${#Project#countryCode}</ws1:countryCode>
                    <ws1:areaCode>${#Project#areaCode}</ws1:areaCode>
                    <ws1:label>${#Project#label}</ws1:label>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <!--Optional:-->
                 </ws1:contactList>
              </ws:payload>
           </ws:acspManagementRequestData>
        </ws:credentialManagementRequestList>
        <ws:runRiskType>ALL</ws:runRiskType>
     </ws:request>
  </ws:updateUser>
```

Code :

```
update_oob_sms = {'credentialManagementRequestList': {
    'acspManagementRequestData': {
        'credentialProvisioningStatus': 'ACTIVE',
        'payload': {
            '@type': 'ns835:OOBSMSManagementRequest',
            'action': 'ADD',
            'contactList': {
                'isDefault': 'true',
                'phoneNumber': '4332223',
                'countryCode': '972',
                'areaCode': '50',
                'label': 'label'
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

> update_user_request = self.soap.client.get_type('ns0:UpdateUserRequest')
>   self.soap.service.updateUser(update_user_request(**update_oob_sms ))
>
> Response : TypeError: {http://ws.csd.rsa.com}AcspManagementRequest() got an
>    unexpected keyword argument 'contactList'. Signature: opcode: xsd:string

When i get type

> print(client.get_type('ns0:AcspManagementRequest'))

Response :

> AcspManagementRequest({http://ws.csd.rsa.com}AcspManagementRequest(opcode: xsd:string))

Looks like it accepts only string. If i try to convert payload value to string and send, i get response as **fault : unknown**. Kindly help